# Checking arrays for same elements and then pushing to a third array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have 2 arrays of objects.

Let's say:

```
arr1 = [object, object, object];
```

and

```
arr2 = [object, object, object];
```

how do I iterate over them and check for a same object property value and then push into a third array.
i have tried this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++){
       if (arr1[i].id == arr2[j].id){
          arr3.push(arr1[i])
    }
  }
```

this does not work however

Comment: What part of that doesn't work? Do you get any console errors? It looks reasonable to me. What output do you get? Are you sure you actually have any matching objects with the same `id`?

Comment: Are the objects in both arrays in the same order?

Comment: @MB no they are not, is that a problem?

Comment: actually, its not because you are checking every possible combination with the double loop

Comment: It seems your [code works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/t17qpkbe/) (assuming you have all 3 close braces) So as per my previous previous comment: Do you have any errors? What output do you get? Are you sure your input is what you expect? You need to provide enough code to replicate the issue, and that includes input arrays

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. including sample input and expected results

Answer (score 3):

you are missing the closing curly braces in your if statement, other thant that it works:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++){
       if (arr1[i].id == arr2[j].id){
          arr3.push(arr1[i])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think that was a typo otherwise I would have got a syntax error

Comment: well, I run your code and it works for me, if it's not working with the fixed semicolon then the issue might have to do with the data in your objects

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using third party libs,.. lodash has a function that will do it for you.

eg.

```
var arr3 = _.intersectionWith(arr1,arr2,function (a,b) { return a.id === b.id })
```

Answer (score 1):

Why nesting loops if you need only 1 (or even none)?

```
arr1.forEach(object => {
    if (arr2.indexOf(object) !== -1) {
        arr3.push(object);
    }
});
```